# 3 panes layout (not 3 columns)

Tags: html, css

I want to have layout, which is similar by structure to Thunderbird classic view ( http://kmgerich.com/pinstripe/screenshots/mail/classic-view.png ) - header with 100% width, 1st pane - left - height - fullscreen (excepting header, ofc), 2nd pane - right top - 50% of screen height (excepting header), right bottom - 50% of screen height. The panes should have fixed height - in case if content has large height, scrollbars should appear.
Now I have smth like this:

```
#header {
    height:30px;  
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;   
}

#right-top {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height:50%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 1px;
    height:50%;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MCC5E/

The current problems: left pane is not full height, right top pane overlap right bottom pane (it can be checked in Firebug).

Is there any way to achieve such layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Znarkus/cwyuv/? I set `pos: abs` on `#pane` to make the divs inside position relative to it. Then `top: 0; bottom: 0;` on `#left` so it fills up the height. Also, don't forget to set the height of `body`.

Comment: This is a modified version of Znarkus' fiddle with the `overflows` set on each `#pane` and `body`.  http://jsfiddle.net/dylanvalade/kKYmf/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more precise than a percentage dimension, use jQuery to set the size of the elements based on the body or outer container's outerHeight and outerWidth. http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

This function can be called as often as needed and extended for the right column elements. If the panes' dimensions are altered by the user or the browser window size is changed, then you call the resize function again.  If you find that there is a little overlap or you want to maintain some margin between your panes, you can just add offset to the height and width by reducing the containerHeight and containerWidth values by something like 5 or 10.

```
// Force sidebar to be the same height as page wrapper
function resizeSidebar() {

    // Capture outerHeight (height+padding+border+margin)
    var containerHeight = $('#pageWrapper').outerHeight(),
        containerWidth = $('#pageWrapper').outerWidth();

    // Percentage math
    var leftHeight = containerHeight - $('#header').outerHeight(),
        leftWidth = containerWidth / 2;

    // Set equal heights
    $('#left').animate({ height: leftHeight, width: leftWidth}, 250);
    // alternatively can set css property $('#left').css({'height' : leftHeight, 'width' : leftWidth});

};
```